# Move dialog controls into tabs?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, mfc

I have a dialog with several controls. Next, I added a 3rd party grid control, which is quite bulky. It looks good, but there is not enough screen space. One desirable option would be to have 2 tabs, one with the existing controls and the other to hold the grid.

It looks as if this "tab" approach will demand a complete re-write of the code. Is there any better way to do this ? Are there any specific concerns when you want to move GUI contols into a tab that you are aware of ?

Comment: Can you post the screenshot?

Comment: Please add tags indicating platform (Linux, mac, iOs, win) and windowing tech (x-windows, wpf, etc)

Comment: Sadly I cannot post a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go for a tabbed dialog, please check this http://hallofshame.gp.co.at/index.php?file=tabs.htm&mode=original to avoid the most trivial gotca:

- You shall avoid putting the dialog controls (e.g. OK and Cancel) button to a tab, as they apply to the whole dialog not to a selected tab
- It is considered to be a bad idea of having tabs in a dialog, because the user can not see all of her inputs when clicking OK. For example, the user changes something on tab1, clicks on tab2 and clicks OK - now the user has the impression she did not change anything (on tab2) but pressing OK still applies his changes. Of course, sometimes tabs are unavoidable, but if you can avoid using them in the modal dialogs, please avoid. A bad example is http://hallofshame.gp.co.at/find95.htm where all search parameters are entered on multiple visually unrelated tabs.
- The tab metaphor is for multiple documents, not for multiple inputs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_(GUI)

I'd rather not use a tab here. You can make the dialog bigger, you can make the grid smaller, you can use layouts to allow the user to make the whole dialog bigger and see more from the grid, and you can have splitters to let the user customize the GUI.

(I found many times a bad idea to use a GUI designer, such as winforms designer. It is a great help initially to lay out the controls. However it is really an obstacle from other perspectives, such as isolating code (and putting that to another tab), and inheriting and extending gui fragments. In short, you'll give up all the flexibility and powers of OOP just in favor of a quicker way to throw the widgets to your form.

If you'd have the existing form in code, you can make a class out of that, and another class for the grid stuff. Then refactor your form to have a tabsheet, and put on the first tab the instance of your first class, and on the second sheet the instance of your grid stuff.

It is not necessarily hard to program GUI from code, once you can hide the complexity of the actual gui framework with some OOP. Let me know if you wish to see an example.)

Comment: Thx for the warning. There won't be such a problem here, the second tab shows the results in a grid, there is no input.

Comment: Hm, I am just guessing your use case. If the grid is output-only, you might consider opening it in a separate dialog "as an output". Or, if it is a kind of search parameters - search result thing then you can consider making the panel showing the input fields possible to hide (and give bigger screen space for the grid) once the search is completed. Use a show/hide button to let the user open the search details fields again. You can also limit the visible input fields using *progressive disclosure*.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be this simple, but if you are using the winforms designer, why can't you just cut the controls, drop in the tab control, and paste in the controls? If you have trouble with code losing wireup to handlers, you can always copy portions of the sourcecode into a notepad first and paste them back after moving controls around the screen.

You can also try dragging and dropping to the tab control. Just make it small with 2 tabs in the corner of the screen. When you drag in, it will keep the positions when you drop. One all controls are in, expand it.

Things like this would work with winforms+c# ... I don't know what screen design editor or Gui technology you're using though. I'm not even sure of the platform. Obviously if not windows then I'm way off the mark...

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010.